# Sort Data Descending

Tags: c#, sorting

I have the following data that its retrieved from two `textbox`. I would like to Sort it Descending by Time. I tried using a Dictionary but I cant insert duplicate values. Any Ideas?

```
ID     time                             ID       time
4       10                              15        19       
12      13      WANT SORTED BY TIME     12        13
15      19      ---->>                  12        13
4       10                              4         10 
12      13                              4         10
```

Comment: Where is the data coming from before it gets to the textboxes?  A database query?  Some objects?

Comment: Dictionary cannot contain duplicate keys so the alternative is called a Lookup http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx

Comment: You could have a List and implement your own IComparer for a simple solution.

Comment: @RQDQ There are many buttons in the screen whenever the user clicks on the buttons it puts them in a multiline textbox. I extracted the data from the textbox and loop thru each line in the textbox and the I use a database query it gets me the IDs and Time. I need to sort them after that.

Comment: @JBKing how would I do that.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx would be the MSDN link about it if you want a non-Linq solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dictionaries do not allow duplicate keys, so that is not what you want here, since your `ID` value is clearly not a unique key value.

Create a class to hold your data and then use Linq's OrderByDescending to sort it:

```
public class MyTimeData {
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public int Time { get; set; }
}

var list = new List<MyTimeData>();
// Add items to the list
list = list.OrderByDescending(d => d.Time).ToList();
```

Comment: How do I add my values to that class from another form, I am a newbie

Comment: List<MyTimeData> tmp = new List<MyTimeData>();        tmp.add(new MyTimeData{Id=1, Time = DateTime.Now} );

Comment: @Apollo - You should really put in some effort if your goal is to learn how to program.

Comment: @mbeckish I am trying to learn, I tried using Dictionary and Lists, but never thought I could use it with another class like that.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I learned something new today. Can you +1 my question somebody voted me down and I dont know why.

Answer (score 0):

```
yourList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Time);
```

Comment: I know how to sort, If I sort one list it wont sort the other one

Comment: when you say "other" is it part of same object? you can chain it by calling ".ThenByDescending(x=>x.ID)"

Answer (score 0):

Another option, if LINQ is not available or something you are interested in, is the `SortedList` data structure (which you can reverse the order to make it descending, as it is ascending by default), which you can use like this:

```
public class MyTimeData {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Time { get; set; }
}

var list = new SortedList<MyTimeData>();

// Add items to sorted list

// Reverse to make it descending
var listDescending = list.Reverse();  

foreach (var item in listDescending)
{
    // Do something with item
}
```